# What does <- mean in Java?

Tags: java

I ran across this example and realized i don't fully understand what's going on here

```
if (a <- b) {
    return false;
}
```

What is `<-` in Java?

Comment: was there spacing in the example you saw or was it just `a<-b`? in other words, is it bad formatting or intentional confusing? and was it in live code? just curious :)

Comment: I'd call this one "fail".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See it in this way:

```
if (a < -b) {
    return false;
}
```

There is no `<-` operator in java.

Related, I've just found this question: [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)

Comment: @Jam: yet strangely enough no one upvoted the question. it is a valid very interesting question, imo.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such operator in java. This means

```
if (a < -b) {

}
```

which is same as

```
if (a < -         b) {

}
```

The `-` sign need not be just by `b`.

For `int` types one could do

```
if (a <-- b) {

}
```

which will be same as

```
if (a < --b) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of stuff is possible.but there is no <- operator in java.it can be -b

int a=4;
    int b=-5;

```
if(a<-b){
    System.out.println("ela");
}
```